# How to read a .txt file that has a flowchart in it and using it in a program

Tags: python-2.7

This is the prompt:

A correct program will allow the user to answer yes (y) or no (n) to any question, subsequently flowing
to the appropriate path in the flowchart. Once an end state is reached, your program should terminate.
You may safely assume that I will not answer a question with something invalid (i.e., not y or n)
when testing.

This is the code to help us solve:

```
    ###########################################################################################
# Name: 
# Date: 
# Description: 
###########################################################################################
import sys

# processes/"plays" the flowchart
# *****this is the only part of the code that you should modify/add to*****
def play(entities):
    # pass is a reserved word that simply means "do nothing"
    # it is used when Python expects code in a block (e.g., a function) but none is provided at the time
    # it usually means that code will be provided at a later time
    pass

########
# MAIN #
########
# make sure that a flowchart file is specified at the command line
if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print "Usage: python {} <file>".format(sys.argv[0])
    exit(0)

# open the flowchart file, read it into a list, and close it
file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
entities = []
for entity in file:
    entities.append(entity.rstrip())
file.close()

# "play" the flowchart
play(entities)
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: You are not wrong i apologize for using this site incorrectly if i am but when it comes to programming and coding i have no experience and my teacher is doing nothing to help with that in class so i put this up in hopes of some guidance at least